# same convertView instance is passed for visible views in CursorAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a strange problem with a custom created CursorAdapter derived class in android:

My getView() implementation is straight textbook seen on many sites/Google talks. However, it seems that for different **positions** (position parameter that this method is called with), this method is being passed the same instance of **convertView**, even though as i see it, these should refer to different object instances, as it should correspond to other visible items in the ListView, and shouldn't reuse the same object instance in case of visible list items...

I have removed the actual part that updates the actual views since the issues reproduces even without it.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        Log.d("dd", "getView()");

        if (convertView == null) {
            Log.d("d", "convertview is null!");

            // create convertView from xml
            convertView = this.mInflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_entry,
                    parent, false);

            // create the viewHolder
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.gameName2);
             viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.gameImage);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            Log.d("dd", "convertview is not null");
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        LinearLayout thisItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
        Log.d("thisItem",
                "This Item is Index "
                        + position
                        + " "
                        + thisItem.toString()
                        + " "
                        + Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(thisItem))
                        + "x: " + thisItem.getX() + " y: " + thisItem.getY());

        this.cur.moveToPosition((int) (getItemId(position) - 1));

        Log.d("dd", "End of getView()");
        return convertView;
    }
```

Running this code produces this output:

> D/dd      (27725): getView() D/d       (27725): convertview is null!
>   D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index 0
>   android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/dd
>   (27725): convertview is not null D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index
>   1 android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/dd
>   (27725): convertview is not null D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index
>   2 android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/dd
>   (27725): convertview is not null D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index
>   3 android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/dd
>   (27725): convertview is not null D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index
>   4 android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/dd
>   (27725): convertview is not null D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index
>   0 android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb5f70 40fb5f70x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/d
>   (27725): convertview is null! D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index 1
>   android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb89f8 40fb89f8x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/d
>   (27725): convertview is null! D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index 2
>   android.widget.LinearLayout@40fb9c48 40fb9c48x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/d
>   (27725): convertview is null! D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index 3
>   android.widget.LinearLayout@40fbae98 40fbae98x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView() D/dd      (27725): getView() D/d
>   (27725): convertview is null! D/thisItem(27725): This Item is Index 4
>   android.widget.LinearLayout@40fbc0e8 40fbc0e8x: 0.0 y: 0.0 D/dd
>   (27725): End of getView()

It can be seen in the beginning that for each position (0 through 4), the same View object hash is being sent...

Comment: (Please post stack traces in code blocks, since quote blocks don't respect line breaks.)  ListViews often call `getView()` multiple times before the layout is drawn, especially if you use `wrap_content` as the height.

Comment: do they call getView multiple times, passing the convertView that was created once? even for different data positions?

Comment: Also, the purpose of getView() as i understand is to create a View for a particular listview item. If this involves populating the item with some images/text/etc, how can i cope with the fact it may be called multiple times per particular item?

Comment: I assume that this is the output from simply starting your app and that you haven't scrolled the ListView. Am I right?

Comment: @sam this is correct, but even without scrolling this results in wrong behaviour. In case i set an image to the listview item, the first item in the list gets a bunch of different pictures (since the same instance is used for a bunch of calls in the beginning as seen in the log).

Comment: Ok, then there is no need to worry.  For whatever reason, ListView needed to do a "dry run" to calculate its height and/or how many rows fit on the screen.  But ListView throws these out since they aren't perfect, they're _guesses_.  You've notice the second time the rows are inflated that they are different Views because these are the rows you actually see.  **In short,** don't sweat it.

Comment: As mentioned in my prev. comment, i am sweating it alright, since visually this appears like a bunch of changes are being done on the first item of the list, only later to be followed by the correct behavior

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25626/discussion-between-sam-and-lysergic-acid)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, set your ListView's height to `match_parent` or another fixed height.

There are many reason that ListView calls `getView()` in the "dry run" manner that you see, the most common is because you have used `wrap_content` as the ListView's height.  Android must inflate a bunch of rows to calculate the height for `wrap_content`, but it cannot use real data since this isn't available yet. So the Adapter throws these *best guesses* out.  Later the layout is (re)created with actual data, which is why you see the each row create twice.

Also a CursorAdapter should maintain the appropriate row itself, you don't need this line:

```
this.cur.moveToPosition((int)(getItemId(position) - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that views are reused by `Convertview`. 
You can delete all the `Convertview` part and for sure it will not reuse undesired views and you will get the desired result (at the cost of some performance...).